# Questions concerning a career in research on or off topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have a question about research careers, or rather PhD programmes but I'm not sure if it is on or off topic. From several threads here on meta I gathered that there is no general consensus on these sort of questions yet and that the chat is a good place to ask first before posting a possibly off-topic question. Since however the chat is rather slow at the moment and the [academia proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/16617/academia) had not launched yet, I repost my question here. I would suggest posting answers to the question itself in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/physics) and answers as to wether my question is on or off topic in this thread.
*(This is my first question on meta. I hope I'm doing this right.)*

> I'm currently working on my Master's thesis in the field of Heavy Ion Physics. I did some work on a statistical model and am now learning about parton distribution functions, fragmentation functions and a tiny bit about the Color Glass Condensate framework. The goal is to try and apply that knowledge to Pb-Pb collisions.
>
> I am very much interested in doing a PhD after I finnish. I would like to do my PhD in a country where I would be required to pay tuition and thus need a specific scholarship. I would be unable to do a PhD in that country without said (or equivalent) scholarship.
>
> My question is: how common it is for physicists to 'change fields' (within physics) between their Master's degree and their PhD degree? I am of course looking for positions where I could do something similar to what I'm doing now. However, I'm open to alternatives. Would it be weird (*read: would it look weird on my application*) to apply for a scholarship for a PhD in e.g. early universe cosmology? I have heard a lecture on GR and one on basic cosmology, but nothing deeper than that. The topic sounds interesting however and I would certainly be willing to learn the required methods.

Answer (score 3):

We have a number of career related questions on the site already, mostly in [soft-questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soft-questions) and [physics-careers](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics-careers). They are a bit of mixed bag in terms of being open/closed.

I'm of mixed mind about them. I've answered several of them myself, but I would not like to see them become a regular feature of the site.

Towards you question, if your country of interest is the USA then many (most?) positions in Ph.D. programs come with tuition support and/or a stipend of some kind or another. (Mind you, *I* didn't have any support for the first year of my graduate studies, but that's on account of my undergrad GPA...) I think much of Europe is similar, though there seems to be considerable variation from country to country.

Comment: Yeah, I feel the same way. As career-related questions go, this one is probably one of the better ones seeing as how it's reasonably specific to physics.