# Can we ask for the physics summer internships options on the 'Physics' Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

I am trying to find summer internships for physics in the USA and as an international student, I am having a tough time finding more options. I was planning to ask this question on the *Physics* Stack Exchange (PSE) site and get some suggestions, but I wasn't really sure if it is an appropriate question to be posted on PSE.

Comment: Related (the intent is not to imply anything): *[Are questions concerning a career in research on or off topic?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/905/)*, *[Education tag and questions on physics education](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14083/)*, *[Resource recommendation for Physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12476/)*, and *[Is it relevant to ask questions regarding careers in physics and not actually some physics concept?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7523/)*.

Comment: Any summer internships I have are posted on my institution’s job portal. I would ignore any requests made as a post here in Meta, and vote to close such a job search request on the main site. Just the way I feel, nothing personal, sticking to corporate guidelines…

Comment: Maybe you also want to check this beautiful answer shared on chemM.SE by @JonCuster https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4875/17368